# Colorizing the titlebar in macOS with multiple colors

Tags: c++, qt, cocoa, titlebar

I have a Qt app that runs on macOS. I found a way to change the color of the titlebar [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/72335/changing-window-titlebar-colour-in-macos), however I want to take it a step further. I want to mimic the titlebar that the Slack and Discord apps use. For example:

[image]

As you can see, the color of the controls in the window extend to the very top of the app's window. I figure there are two ways to accomplish what I want:

1. I can build on the code pasted above. Looking through some of the Apple developer documentation, I think I can create a couple `NsWindow`s on top of the titlebar with whatever width I want and attach the titlebar as a parent for those windows. Once I do that I should be able to make the same `backgroundColor()` color call for each one. Of course, this will require me to keep track of when the controls or window are resized and adjust the `NsWindow`s of the titlebar, and I am not sure what (if any) issues that could cause.
2. Maybe there is a way to essentially set the height of the titlebar to `0`? I wonder if that's what the Discord app is doing because:

[image]

if you look closely, the edit box that says "Find or start a conversation" is vertically lined with the close, minimize and maximize buttons, as is the "Activity" label. But if the controls do extend to the top of the app's window then how are the standard app buttons getting painted?

I'd be curious to know how Slack and Discord accomplish this even though I know they're not using Qt.

I realize there is not a Qt solution since Qt does not paint the titlebar. I know this will be OS-specific, but since I do not have any real experience with Objective-C++ or working with Cocoa (all of my programming experience on macOS has been standard C++ with non-UI or Qt-based code) I'd appreciate any suggestions or guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Natively this is done with [`fullSizeContentView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/stylemask/1644646-fullsizecontentview) and [`titlebarAppearsTransparent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419167-titlebarappearstransparent) properties of `NSWindow`. Once you set them to `true`, you can draw or place controls beneath the title bar.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to accomplish what I wanted with:     ```NSWindowStyleMask windowMask =
            NSWindowStyleMaskFullSizeContentView
                | NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless
                | NSWindowStyleMaskTitled
                | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable
                | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable
                | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable;

    [window setStyleMask: windowMask];```